# Connection closed before full header was received in a local server

Tags: http, flutter, dart

When I tried to request data from the local server, the following error occurred:

`ClientException (Connection closed before full header was received)`

```
void authanticate() async {
      String authString =
          'http' + '://' + ip + ':' + port + '/' + rec + '?password=' + pass;
      print(authString);

      var response = await get(authString);
      print(response.statusCode);

      print(response.body);
}
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: looks like server error, please add the same on a web browser and check you are getting data or not.

Comment: is the 'get' method wrapping http.get() ?

Comment: try to open the complete URL in your browser that the ``authString`` variable returns and check if it works or not.

Comment: @jitsm555 I check the URL in the web browser and I got the data.

Comment: @thusith.92 I tried `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;` with `var response = await http.get(authString);` but the error still occured.

Comment: @Binuwara, Are you using an emulator or a physical device?

Comment: @thusith.92 I’m using a physical device which is running android 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be used as `http.get(authString)`

```
void authanticate() async {
      String authString =
          'https' + '://' + ip + ':' + port + '/' + rec + '?password=' + pass;
      print(authString);

      var response = await http.get(authString);
      print(response.statusCode);

      print(response.body);
}
```

Comment: I tried `http.get(authString)` with `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`, but the error still occurred. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Without URL I don't think, I can help you much more on this.  or maybe just directly add your URL as String authString = "Entire URL without concatenation"; There may be issue with generated string here. Also check your internet connection :)

Comment: I tried with the full URL which loads fine on the web browser: `String authString = 'http://192.168.1.4:8741/requests?password=toor';`. However, the same error still occurred.

Comment: Ip address is of your local machine, not sure how it will run on mobile. Have you hosted anything on your machine

Comment: The IP address is from a device which hosts the server and it runs on the same network.

Comment: Could you just check the same URL on the mobile web browser? it should not work there.

Comment: You're right. The URL doesn't work on the mobile web browser. However, the URL worked on my iPad and my PC. Is this error only related to android devices?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220662/discussion-between-jitsm555-and-binuwara).